# How to Add Date/Time to Each Line before exporting to CSV

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I've got a nice working powershell function called PSO.
The PSO function searches for one or more specific windows processes based on the given input/parameter. When a procesname matches the searchparameter it exports/appends the process owner and more info to a csv file. All good so far.

Now I really like to add date and time info to each line PowerShell writes to the csv. I've been struggling with it for a while now. I've got somehting simular working in VBScript, but i'm really starting to like powershell and like to see and learn more.

Below The PSO Function, I assume this is the area where Date and Time should be generated and added... right?

```
Function Get-PSO($searchString)
# http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/12/17/get-process-owners.aspx
# Usage: Get-PSO * OR Get-PSO exp*,*paint*,calc*,notepad*
# Sample Export2csv: Get-PSO notepad* | Export-CSV $env:userprofile\desktop\export.csv -Append 

# A few date/time formats for later use... i hope
$date=(Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-d")
$time=(Get-Date -format "HH:mm:ss")
$datetime=(Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-d HH:mm")

$foundProcess = ps $searchString -ea silentlycontinue
if($foundProcess -eq $null) { return; }
$foundprocess | % {
gwmi Win32_Process -Filter ("Handle={0}" -f $_.id ) | 
 % { Add-Member -TypeName Type -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Owner -Value ($_.GetOwner().User) -PassThru } |
# See below my last attempt to get this tot work
# % { Add-Member -TypeName Type -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Owner -Value ($_.GetOwner().User) -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Date -Value $date -PassThru } |
  select Name, Handle, Owner, Type
}
```

When I run the function ; Get-PSO notepad* | Export-CSV $env:userprofile\desktop\export.csv -Append) I get the following result:

Name;Handle;Owner;Type

notepad++.exe;7736;Dave;

I like to Add Date/Time and the result should look something like:

Name;Handle;Owner;Date;Time;DateTime;Type

notepad++.exe;7736;Dave;5-4-2015;20:07;5-4-2015 20:07;

Anyone? some help or ideas would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Function Get-PSO($searchString) {
    # http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/12/17/get-process-owners.aspx
    # Usage: Get-PSO * OR Get-PSO exp*,*paint*,calc*,notepad*
    # Sample Export2csv: Get-PSO notepad* | Export-CSV $env:userprofile\desktop\export.csv -Append 

    # A few date/time formats for later use... i hope
    $date=(Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-d")
    $time=(Get-Date -format "HH:mm:ss")
    $datetime=(Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-d HH:mm")

    $foundProcess = ps $searchString -ea silentlycontinue
    if($foundProcess -eq $null) { return; }
    $foundprocess | % {         
        gwmi Win32_Process -Filter ("Handle={0}" -f $_.id ) | 
            % { 
                Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Owner -Value ($_.GetOwner().User) -PassThru
                Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Date -Value $date -PassThru
                Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Time -Value $time -PassThru
                Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DateTime -Value $datetime -PassThru
                Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Type -Value "" -PassThru
            } |
            select Name, Handle, Owner, Date, Time, DateTime, Type
    }
}
```

Each `Add-Member` command adds a property to the individual results.  The `Name` parameter will be the column name in the exported CSV and the `Value` parameter will be the value.  The `select` command (actually `Select-Object`) filters the results to the listed subset of properties.

Alternatively, you could do all of this using just Select-Object and [Calculated Properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx).

```
Function Get-PSO($searchString) {
    # http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/12/17/get-process-owners.aspx
    # Usage: Get-PSO * OR Get-PSO exp*,*paint*,calc*,notepad*
    # Sample Export2csv: Get-PSO notepad* | Export-CSV $env:userprofile\desktop\export.csv -Append 

    # A few date/time formats for later use... i hope
    $date=(Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-d")
    $time=(Get-Date -format "HH:mm:ss")
    $datetime=(Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-d HH:mm")

    $foundProcess = ps $searchString -ea silentlycontinue
    if($foundProcess -eq $null) { return; }
    $foundprocess | % {         
        gwmi Win32_Process -Filter ("Handle={0}" -f $_.id ) | 
            select-Object Name, Handle, 
                @{Name='Owner'; Expression={$_.GetOwner().User}}, 
                @{Name='Date'; Expression={$date}}, 
                @{Name='Time'; Expression={$time}}, 
                @{Name='DateTime'; Expression={$datetime}}, 
                @{Name='Type'; Expression={''}}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx David! The Select-Object alternative works great! And the technet article is very usefull to!!